# using JNSI call to get window object gwt

Tags: gwt, jsni

Just reading JSNI and wondering can we convert JavaScriptObject, returned from the below function call to arc.gui.gwt.widget.window.Window and then use it to call Window object functions.

```
public static native JavaScriptObject window() /*-{
    return $wnd;
}-*/;
```

Comment: What is a arc.gui.gwt.widget.window.Window ?????

Comment: Native `$wnd` is `com.google.gwt.user.client.Window`. Call all `Window` methods directly from Java instead of getting `$wnd`.